# Android: How to correlate ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events that come from the same drag motion

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I want to allow the user to drag controls vertically in my OpenGL view (like a scrollbar). To implement this I plan to do the following:

- Use `onTouchEvent` to listen for motion events
- On `ACTION_DOWN`, record the vertical offset between the touch location and the control
- On `ACTION_MOVE`, inch the control upwards/downwards depending on which way the user drags
- On `ACTION_UP`, delete the offset

I want to support the user dragging multiple controls at the same time, so I need to be able to get some kind of ID from the `ACTION_DOWN` event that I can use as the hashtable entry for the offset. Later, when handling `ACTION_MOVE` I need to be able to get that same ID to look up the offset in the hashtable, in order to ensure that we don't mix up 2 controls that are being dragged at the same time. How do I get this 'ID' so I can correlate the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_MOVE` events that come from the same drag motion?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `MotionEvent.downTime` was the property I was looking for.